# How do i store current time in database using javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have put Label outside the update panel ,so that if user get any message related to error or confirmation it get seen on top right side without Loading the whole page, but label is not getting any text , when i comment update panel it works but it loads whole page that i don't won't . So Help-Out .

### Here is Page Design Code where label is set :

```
<div>
  <asp:Label ID ="se" CssClass="mess" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" > 
  </asp:Label>
</div>

<div>
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">

  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger EventName="Click" ControlID="b1" />
  </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
      <div>
        <asp:Button ID="b1" runat="server"  Text="Submit."  />
      </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

### CSS i used for Label .

```
.mess{
    z-index:3;
   -o-box-shadow:1px 1px 1px 1px #322e2e;
   -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 1px 1px #322e2e;
   -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 1px 1px #322e2e;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 1px 1px #322e2e;
    float:right;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:25px 25px 25px 0;
    background-color:#5db620;
    color:#f1eded;
    margin:auto 5% auto auto;
    display:none;      
    text-wrap:normal;
}
```

### Javascript i used for label : this script i used when i commented the update panel , so when page is loaded & if label get any text it disappear after 10 sec .

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= se.ClientID %>').fadeOut(10000);
    });
 </script>
```

C# code-behind used for label :Here i changing  the css by using  attribute [disply:inline]

### so whatever the text in label can be seen on button click .

```
protected void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    se.Attributes.Add("style", "display:inline");
    se.Text = "Ok";   
}
```

Comment: You don't need to include your CSS in this particular ASP.NET specific question.

Comment: Also, your question summary doesn't relate to the question details. In your question summary you state the need to store current time to a db using javascript but in your question details you state the issue being that the asp:Label is not updating on a Ajax postback.

Comment: @Narendra Singh Rathore edit your header it doesnt match the question itself also try mmy answer i have edited some of your codes and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

The asp:Label with the ID="se" must be in the UpdatePanel to be updated on a Async postback.

Answer (score 0):

TRY This your labels should be inside the update panel Copy this and try to replace your code i edited some of that to this and it work just fine for me

```
<div>
    <asp:scriptmanager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
    <asp:updatepanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" updatemode="Conditional">
        
                    <Triggers>
                
                        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="b1" />
        
                    </Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
              <div>
              <asp:Label ID ="se" CssClass="mess" runat="server"> </asp:Label>
              </div>
              <div>
              <asp:Button ID="b1" runat="server"  Text="Submit."  />
              </div>
              </ContentTemplate>
              </asp:updatepanel>
    </div>
```

Screen shots

[image]

[image]

the update panel works now

Comment: I Have Tried It But the Label is not getting any text which executes on button click

Comment: @NarendraSinghRathore i just edited it can you try it again? thanks